# Python 2.7 TKinter Scrolling canvas with widgets alongside non-scrolling region

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create an user interface that has both a scrolling section and and a non-scrolling section. In the scrolling section will be a list of labels and user entries and in the non-scroll-able section will be information on how to fill in the entries. I am thinking of using a separate window to display the information but was wondering whether it is possible to display both in the same window.

I have adapted the code from the response to this question:  [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter) however when I try to add the message region and scrolling regions into separate frames the Python shell crashes and does not open. Here is the code I am working with.

```
import Tkinter as tk

labelList = []

for i in range(100):
    labelList.append(["This is label %s  " %(i),"99"])


class Example(tk.Frame):

    #Creation of scrollable canvas 

    def __init__(self, root, labelList):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        #Creating Scrollable and Non-scrollable frames 

        self.scrollFrame = tk.Frame(root,bg = "red")
        self.scrollFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 3, columnspan = 2)

        self.no_scrollFrame = tk.Frame(root,bg = "blue")
        self.no_scrollFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 2, rowspan = 3, columnspan = 2)

        #Canvas assigned to Scrollable Frame

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.scrollFrame, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.scrollFrame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

        #Message assigned to non-Scrollable Frame


        messageText = """

    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n
    Information \n        

    """


        self.Message1 = tk.Message(self.no_scrollFrame, text=messageText)
        self.Message1.grid(row = 1, rowspan = len(labelList)+1, column = 2)

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.entry ={}
        self.label = {}

        self.populate() 

    def populate(self):

        i=0

        if len(labelList) != 0:
                 for item in labelList:
                        e = tk.Entry(self.frame)
                        e.grid(row = i+1, column = 1)
                        self.entry[item[0]] = e

                        labelText =  item[0] + " (" + item[1] + ") "                  

                        lb = tk.Label(self.frame,text=labelText)
                        lb.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
                        self.label[item[0]] = lb
                        i += 1
        else:
            master.destroy()


    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example(root,labelList).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message ? I see `"cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid"`

Comment: you have to use `self` instead of `root` in both `tk.Frame(root, ...)`

Comment: Ah thanks, I did not realise I could use cmd to see the error message, I was running in Idle and the shell just hung with no message.